# I need an HTML listbox with UTC TimeZones

Tags: html, listbox, timezone

I need an html listbox(dropbox) with all the timezones just like in the windows7 timezone listbox, if theres a sample available somewhere, i couldnt find it on google, or maybe i'm not that lucky, however i can rewrite the listbox, but just thought if there's an already coded list !

Please not, it has to be UTC, cuz i found a GMT one at [Link Here](http://www.michaelapproved.com/articles/timezone-dropdown-select-list/)

thanks alot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GMT = UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC):

> UTC is closely related to Universal Time and Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) and within informal or casual contexts where sub-second precision is not required, it can be used interchangeably.

Do a search+replace of "GMT" to "UTC" and you're done.

Comment: Not logical, since lets say (GMT -5:00) Eastern Time (US &amp; Canada), Bogota, Lima, if i search+replace, it will be UTC -5, which is not true.

Comment: for some stupid reason i kept that thought that UTC is different!, sorry again! :) thanks alot!

Comment: @Emad no problem. I would tend to use "GMT" for less confusion - it's better known, and people tend to be unsure what UTC is.

Comment: i see, just like my case! then i'll keep it GMT :) thanks again